How can I optimise my cost objective function while limiting total time taken for the whole process?
For context, I just started using AnyLogic a week ago and am quite new at this. I am trying to make a simple process model of a specific logistics process and I want to be able to find the optimal total cost of the process (which is calculated by the time taken of each sub process multiplied by the cost of each worker used) by limitng the total amount of the time the whole process takes.

I made my objective function the summation of the costs from the 3 different resources that I use and I wanted to put the total time taken for the process as a constraint, however I am struggling to find a way to do this.

On the optimization experiment, I will assume you already know and have the objective function configured.
However, you also want some constraint on the maximum processing time - however, in AnyLogic experiment the constraints are only pre-conditions.
What you are describing is a Requirement. These are evaluated post-simulation, and they can have any expression.
For example, if you have an output you could add root.total_time <= 10 as a requirement (a post-simulation evaluated constraint).

Hi @Enrico, thanks for the reply
How would I define root.total_time?
I tried to make a start counter at the source and an end counter at my sink, and when the counters are equal my sink would then call a function to set my variable total_time = time(). I tried to use this root.total_time <= 10 as my requirement but the optimisation experiment results are always differing and do not make sense just from simple calculations

You could create a variable called total_time, and at each sink you could have total_time = time() - this way, the variable will be updated any time an agent leaves the model.
